# What is this (possibly Swedish) military uniform? Perhaps cavalry?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

This military uniform is from around 1900. I think it is Swedish, and it looks like a cavalry one. It's of my great-grandfather who (so I’m told) fought for Sweden (against whom?) and was promised Swedish Crown land when the war was won. However, the promise was reneged on, so he went to the Faeroe Islands to work as a miner. There, he met my great-grandmother, etc.

[image: Picture of a man in uniform]

I am interested in knowing what uniform this is and whether we can drill down further. For example, to the division, or regiment, maybe?

Comment: In 1900 Sweden was about halfway through its much-vaunted [200 years of peace](https://www.sipri.org/news/2014/sipri-experts-reflect-200-years-peace-sweden), so I think something in this story isn't quite adding up.

Comment: I think it may be a distorted echo of the end of the [allotment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotment_system) system, which started to happen around that time. (The [last allotment soldier](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knut_Ram%C3%A9n) left the army in 1971, apparently.)

Comment: Also, the uniform seems to look more like artillery than cavalry. There are some PDFs if you google for "svenska arméns uniformer".

Comment: A good web page [here](http://www.hhogman.se/uniforms-army-sweden-1800s-artillery1.htm) would initially appear to confirm @TomasBy information about artillery uniforms.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 9):

It is an m/1872 uniform for the artillery, enlisted man or NCO. The white collar indicates it is for No3 (from 1914 A3) [Wendes Artilleriregemente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendes_Artillery_Regiment). It looks cavalry because the Swedish artillery back then was "riding artillery", they rode the horses that dragged the guns.

The headgear is a Käppi m/1880 and the sword a Sabel m/1889, which means the photo was taken sometime after 1889. Sweden was not involved in any wars at that time.

[Wendes Artillery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendes_Artillery_Regiment) was stationed in [Scania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sk%C3%A5ne_County), in [Kristianstad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kristianstad) and was part of I. Arméfördelningen (1st Army Division) along with the I6, I7, I11 and I25 infantry regiments and the K5, K6 and K7 cavalry regiments. The Arméfördelning was an administrative unit rather than a tactical unit.

He would have been manning an 8cm Kanon m/1863 (muzzle-loaded rifled iron cannon), 8,4cm Kanon m/1881 (breech-loaded rifled steel cannon) or 7,5cm Kanon m/02 (breech-loaded rifled steel recoil cannon with hydro-pneumatic recoil mechanism) depending on when the photo is taken.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In English the term for mobile artillery is 'horse artillery'.

Comment: Is "7,5cm" equal to "7 centimetres and a half"?

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?